# Webpack: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am setting up typescript with webpack, using `awesome-typescript-loader`. However webpack is giving me this error on build:

> ERROR in ./src/logic/Something.ts
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected
>   token (2:19) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file
>   type.

here is a piece of code from `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|less)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
                }, {
                    loader: "less-loader"
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".css", ".less"]
    }
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx":  "react" 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

`Something.ts` file:

```
class Something {
    constructor(str: string) {
        console.log(str);
    }
}

export { Something };
```

Do you have any ideas where the issue might be? Thanks!

Comment: What's the content of `Something.ts`? You could potentially be importing something that you haven't defined in your webpack config.

Comment: it is a super simple .ts file, I just wanted to get it working, please see the update

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: from package.json file: `"webpack": "^3.8.1"`

Comment: Okay cool, and have you tried this syntax: 

`{
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                use: {
                  loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
 }`

It seems that webpack v3 requires that kind of syntax.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but I get the same error

Comment: @fshock I've managed to get it working by assigning an array instead of an object to the `use` property. Post it as an answer if you wish so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, not a problem. Will do.

Comment: Yes, @NikosParaskevopoulos, `/\.jsx?$/` should be enough to test for both file types

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[webpack v3](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration) requires using `use` instead of directly writing the `loader` rule for loading `loaders`.

Do it like this, rather:

```
 {
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
 }
```